# Constraints on slider jquery + callng javascript function at page loadto call javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, d3.js

I have some code which plots a certain mathematical function and enables the user to change certain specific parameters of the function on the fly enabling the user to see the change of it.

I have two questions with which I need some help.

i) I am using the jquery UI library which provides a [slider](https://jqueryui.com/slider/). I use this slider to enable the user to change a specific parameter in a certain range. Normally there are no constraints on the parameter. However, in this case I need that the following equality holds `min` <= `mode` <= `max`. Currently I have solved this with some code in the `slide` event of the slider. The code basically checks the equality and if it is violated it sets the parameter to either its minimum or maximum possible value.

Visually, however, it is possible to slide further. However, after I the slider is let loose by the user, the `change` event has been called and I change the parameter to either its minimum or maximum possible value. Is it possible to make sure that also visually the slider is does not violates the constraint?

ii) When I load the page there is no plot visible yet on the page. That is because I seem to be unable to call the function `redraw()` when the page is loading, see the code at the bottom. Why is `redraw()` not being called?

Snippet, see below or http://jsfiddle.net/qraLt1p3/11/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>MPERT</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
svg {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
  
rect {
    fill: transparent;
}
  
.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
  
.line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
    clip-path: url(#clip);
}
  
.grid .tick {
    stroke: lightgrey;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
  
.grid path {
    stroke-width: 0;
}

#slider-pertmin, #slider-pertmode, #slider-pertmax {
 float: right;
 width: 120px;
 margin: 7px;
}

.ui-slider-horizontal {
 height: 8px;
 width: 200px;
}

.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
 height: 15px;
 width: 5px;
 padding-left: 5px;
}

#plot {
  background-color:#f9f9f9;
 border:solid 1px #ddd;
 padding:10px;
  width:250px;
}
 
#plotOptions {
 background-color:#f9f9f9;
 border:solid 1px #ddd;
 padding:10px;
}
 
.block label { 
 display: inline-block; 
 width: 60px; 
 text-align: right; 
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
 // Log-gamma function
 gammaln = function gammaln(x)
 {
  var cof = [ 76.18009172947146,  -86.50532032941677,      24.01409824083091,
        -1.231739572450155,   0.1208650973866179e-2, -0.5395239384953e-5];

  var j = 0;
  var ser = 1.000000000190015;
  var xx, y, tmp;

  tmp = (y = xx = x) + 5.5;
  tmp -= (xx + 0.5) * Math.log(tmp);

  for (; j < 6; j++)
   ser += cof[j] / ++y;

  return Math.log(2.5066282746310005 * ser / xx) - tmp;
 };
 
 // Gamma function
 gammafn = function gammafn(x) 
 {
  var p = [    -1.716185138865495,    24.76565080557592,   -379.80425647094563,
        629.3311553128184,     866.9662027904133,  -31451.272968848367,
        -36144.413418691176,    66456.14382024054];

  var q = [    -30.8402300119739,     315.35062697960416, -1015.1563674902192,
       -3107.771671572311,    22538.118420980151,    4755.8462775278811,
     -134659.9598649693,    -115132.2596755535];
   
  var fact = false,
   n = 0,
   xden = 0,
   xnum = 0,
   y = x,
   i, 
   z, 
   yi, 
   res, 
   sum, 
   ysq;

  if (y <= 0) {
   res = y % 1 + 3.6e-16;
   
   if (res) {
    fact = (!(y & 1) ? 1 : -1) * Math.PI / Math.sin(Math.PI * res);
    y = 1 - y;
   } else
    return Infinity;
  }

  yi = y;

  if (y < 1)
   z = y++;
  else
   z = (y -= n = (y | 0) - 1) - 1;

  for (i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
   xnum = (xnum + p[i]) * z;
   xden = xden * z + q[i];
  }

  res = xnum / xden + 1;

  if (yi < y)
   res /= yi;
  else if (yi > y) {
   for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    res *= y;
    y++;
   }
  }

  if (fact)
   res = fact / res;

  return res;
 };

 // Beta function
 betafn = function betafn(x,y) 
 {
  // ensure arguments are positive
  if (x <= 0 || y <= 0)
   return undefined;

  // make sure x + y doesn't exceed the upper limit of usable values
  return (x + y > 170)
   ? Math.exp(betaln(x, y))
   : gammafn(x) * gammafn(y) / gammafn(x + y);
 };
 
 // Natural logarithm of Beta function
 betaln = function betaln(x, y) 
 {
  return gammaln(x) + gammaln(y) - gammaln(x + y);
 };
 
 $(function() {
  $("#slider-pertmin").slider({
   range: "min",
   value: 1,
   min: 1,
   max: 20,
   step: 0.1,
   slide: function(event,ui) {
    if (ui.value > $("#slider-pertmode").slider("value")) {
     $("#pertmin").val($("#slider-pertmode").slider("value") - 0.1);
     $("#slider-pertmin").slider("value",$("#slider-pertmode").slider("value") - 0.1)
    } else
     $("#pertmin").val(ui.value);

    redraw(); 
   },
   change: function(event,ui) {
     $("#slider-pertmin").slider("value",$("#pertmin").val());
   }
  });

  $("#slider-pertmode").slider({
   range: "min",
   value: 3,
   min: 1,
   max: 20,
   step: 0.1,
   slide: function(event,ui) {
    if (ui.value < $("#slider-pertmin").slider("value")) {
     $("#pertmode").val($("#slider-pertmin").slider("value") + 0.1);
     $("#slider-pertmode").slider("value",$("#slider-pertmin").slider("value") + 0.1);
    } else if (ui.value > $("#slider-pertmax").slider("value")) {
     $("#pertmode").val($("#slider-pertmax").slider("value") - 0.1);
     $("#slider-pertmode").slider("value",$("#slider-pertmax").slider("value") - 0.1);
    } else
     $("#pertmode").val(ui.value);

    redraw();
   },
   change: function(event,ui) {
     $("#slider-pertmode").slider("value",$("#pertmode").val());
   }
  });

  $("#slider-pertmax").slider({
   range: "min",
   value: 6,
   min: 1,
   max: 20,
   step: 0.1,
   slide: function(event,ui) {
    if (ui.value < $("#slider-pertmode").slider("value")) {
     $("#pertmax").val($("#slider-pertmode").slider("value") + 0.1);
     $("#slider-pertmax").slider("value",$("#slider-pertmode").slider("value") + 0.1);
    } else
     $("#pertmax").val(ui.value);

    redraw();
   },
   change: function(event,ui) {
        $("#slider-pertmax").slider("value",$("#pertmax").val());
   }
  });

  $("#pertmin").val($("#slider-pertmin").slider("value"));
  $("#pertmode").val($("#slider-pertmode").slider("value"));
  $("#pertmax").val($("#slider-pertmax").slider("value"));
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="plot"></div>
<div id="plotOptions" class="ui-widget" style="width:250px">
 <div class="block"> 
  <label for="pertmin">min:</label> <input type="value" id="pertmin" style="border:none; background: transparent; width:40px;" />
  <div class="ui-slider" id="slider-pertmin" />
 </div>
 <div class="block"> 
  <label for="pertmode">mode:</label> <input type="value" id="pertmode" style="border:none; background: transparent; width:40px;" />
  <div class="ui-slider" id="slider-pertmode" />
 </div>
 <div class="block">
  <label for="pertmax">max:</label> <input type="value" id="pertmax" style="border:none; background: transparent; width:40px;" />
  <div class="ui-slider" id="slider-pertmax" />
 </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var pert = {
  min: 2,
  mode: 4,
  max: 9
 };

 pert.mu   = (pert.min + 4*pert.mode + pert.max)/6;
 pert.a1   = 6*(pert.mu - pert.min)/(pert.max - pert.min);
 pert.a2   = 6*(pert.max - pert.mu)/(pert.max - pert.min);
 pert.beta = betafn(pert.a1,pert.a2);

    var data = [];

    for (var k = pert.min; k < pert.max; k += 0.1) {
      data.push({
        x: k,
        y: (1/pert.beta)*(Math.pow(k - pert.min,pert.a1 - 1) * 
                    Math.pow(pert.max - k,pert.a2 - 1)) /
        Math.pow(pert.max - pert.min,pert.a1 + pert.a2 - 1)
      });
    }

 var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 35,
        left: 50
     },
  width = 250 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([pert.min, pert.max])
      .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, 1])
      .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis1 = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom")
      .ticks(5)
      .innerTickSize(-6)
      .outerTickSize(0)
      .tickPadding(7);

    var yAxis1 = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left")
      .ticks(5)
      .innerTickSize(-6)
      .outerTickSize(0)
      .tickPadding(7);

    var xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("top")
      .ticks(5)
      .innerTickSize(-6)
      .tickPadding(-20)
      .outerTickSize(0)
      .tickFormat("");

    var yAxis2 = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left")
      .ticks(5)
      .innerTickSize(6)
      .tickPadding(-20)
      .outerTickSize(0)
      .tickFormat("");

    var xGrid = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom")
      .tickSize(-height, -height, 0)
      .tickFormat("");

    var yGrid = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left")
      .ticks(5)
      .tickSize(-width, -width, 0)
      .tickFormat("");
   
    var line = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.x);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.y);
      })
      .interpolate("linear");
   
    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
      .x(x)
      .y(y)
      .scaleExtent([1, 1])
      .on("zoom",redraw);
      
    var svg = d3.select("#plot").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
      .call(zoom);
   
    // Add x grid
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x grid")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xGrid);

    // Add y grid
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y grid")
      .call(yGrid);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x1 axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis1);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y1 axis")
      .call(yAxis1);

    /* append additional X axis */
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x2 axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + [0, 0] + ")")
      .call(xAxis2);

    /* append additional y axis */
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y2 axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + [width, 0] + ")")
      .call(yAxis2);

    // Add x axis label  
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + "," + (height + margin.bottom) + ")")
        .style("font-size","15")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("x axis");

    // Add y axis label
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y",0 - margin.left)
        .attr("x",0 - (height / 2))
        .attr("dy", "1em")
        .style("font-size","15")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("y axis");

    svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", "clip")
      .append("rect")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);
      
    svg.append("rect")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

    svg.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")

    function redraw() {
  pert.min  = $("#slider-pertmin").slider("value");
  pert.mode = $("#slider-pertmode").slider("value");
  pert.max  = $("#slider-pertmax").slider("value");
  pert.mu   = (pert.min + 4*pert.mode + pert.max)/6;
  pert.a1   = 6*(pert.mu - pert.min)/(pert.max - pert.min);
  pert.a2   = 6*(pert.max - pert.mu)/(pert.max - pert.min);
  pert.beta = betafn(pert.a1,pert.a2);
  
  x.domain([pert.min, pert.max]);
 
  svg.select(".x1.axis").call(xAxis1);
  svg.select(".y1.axis").call(yAxis1);
  svg.select(".x2.axis").call(xAxis2);
  svg.select(".y2.axis").call(yAxis2);
  svg.select(".x.grid").call(xGrid);
  svg.select(".y.grid").call(yGrid);
  
  var data = [];

  for (var k = pert.min; k < pert.max; k += 0.1) {
   data.push({
    x: k,
    y: (1/pert.beta)*(Math.pow(k - pert.min,pert.a1 - 1) * 
          Math.pow(pert.max - k,pert.a2 - 1)) /
          Math.pow(pert.max - pert.min,pert.a1 + pert.a2 - 1)
   });
  }

  d3.select(".line").attr("d",line(data));
    }
    
    redraw();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

1.) On your UI question, I would use a range slider to represent my min/max. I'd then get a bit fancy and update the min/max (and width) of my mode slider to force it always between the min/max.

2.) You are calling your initial `redraw` before the sliders have been initialized.  This is because slider initialization is done inside the [document.ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) event while your initial `redraw` is not.  A simple fix is:

```
$(function() {
  redraw();
});
```

---

To expand on my answer a bit, here's a rough example of how I would implement your first question.  Note, I swapped out the jquery slider with a `d3` one based on this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4349545).  I always look for a `d3` based answer.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>MPERT</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    svg {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    
    rect {
      fill: transparent;
    }
    
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    
    .line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
      clip-path: url(#clip);
    }
    
    .grid .tick {
      stroke: lightgrey;
      opacity: 0.7;
    }
    
    .grid path {
      stroke-width: 0;
    }
    
    circle {
      -webkit-transition: fill-opacity 250ms linear;
    }
    
    .selecting circle {
      fill-opacity: .2;
    }
    
    .selecting circle.selected {
      stroke: #f00;
    }
    
    .resize path {
      fill: #666;
      fill-opacity: .8;
      stroke: #000;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
    
    .brush .extent {
      fill-opacity: .125;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    
    #plot {
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      border: solid 1px #ddd;
      padding: 10px;
      width: 250px;
    }
    
    #plotOptions {
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      border: solid 1px #ddd;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
    .block label {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 60px;
      text-align: right;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Log-gamma function
    gammaln = function gammaln(x) {
      var cof = [76.18009172947146, -86.50532032941677, 24.01409824083091, -1.231739572450155, 0.1208650973866179e-2, -0.5395239384953e-5];

      var j = 0;
      var ser = 1.000000000190015;
      var xx, y, tmp;

      tmp = (y = xx = x) + 5.5;
      tmp -= (xx + 0.5) * Math.log(tmp);

      for (; j < 6; j++)
        ser += cof[j] / ++y;

      return Math.log(2.5066282746310005 * ser / xx) - tmp;
    };

    // Gamma function
    gammafn = function gammafn(x) {
      var p = [-1.716185138865495, 24.76565080557592, -379.80425647094563,
        629.3311553128184, 866.9662027904133, -31451.272968848367, -36144.413418691176, 66456.14382024054
      ];

      var q = [-30.8402300119739, 315.35062697960416, -1015.1563674902192, -3107.771671572311, 22538.118420980151, 4755.8462775278811, -134659.9598649693, -115132.2596755535];

      var fact = false,
        n = 0,
        xden = 0,
        xnum = 0,
        y = x,
        i,
        z,
        yi,
        res,
        sum,
        ysq;

      if (y <= 0) {
        res = y % 1 + 3.6e-16;

        if (res) {
          fact = (!(y & 1) ? 1 : -1) * Math.PI / Math.sin(Math.PI * res);
          y = 1 - y;
        } else
          return Infinity;
      }

      yi = y;

      if (y < 1)
        z = y++;
      else
        z = (y -= n = (y | 0) - 1) - 1;

      for (i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        xnum = (xnum + p[i]) * z;
        xden = xden * z + q[i];
      }

      res = xnum / xden + 1;

      if (yi < y)
        res /= yi;
      else if (yi > y) {
        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
          res *= y;
          y++;
        }
      }

      if (fact)
        res = fact / res;

      return res;
    };

    // Beta function
    betafn = function betafn(x, y) {
      // ensure arguments are positive
      if (x <= 0 || y <= 0)
        return undefined;

      // make sure x + y doesn't exceed the upper limit of usable values
      return (x + y > 170) ? Math.exp(betaln(x, y)) : gammafn(x) * gammafn(y) / gammafn(x + y);
    };

    // Natural logarithm of Beta function
    betaln = function betaln(x, y) {
      return gammaln(x) + gammaln(y) - gammaln(x + y);
    };
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="plot"></div>
  <div id="plotOptions" class="ui-widget" style="width:250px">
  </div>

  <script>

var margin = {top: 5, right: 20, bottom: 5, left: 20},
    width = 250 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 50 - margin.top - margin.bottom
    min = 0, max = 20;

var brushX = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width])
    .domain([min, max]);

var brush = d3.svg.brush()
    .x(brushX)
    .extent([0, 20])
    .on("brush", brushmove);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(height / 3)
    .startAngle(0)
    .endAngle(function(d, i) { return i ? -Math.PI : Math.PI; });

var svg = d3.select("#plotOptions").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height/2 + ")")
    .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(brushX).orient("bottom"));

var brushg = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "brush")
    .call(brush);

brushg.selectAll(".resize").append("path")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," +  height / 2 + ")")
    .attr("d", arc);

brushg.selectAll("rect")
    .attr("height", height);

var mode = 10;
var modeRect = svg.append("rect")
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("width", 10)
  .attr("y", 0)
  .attr("x", brushX(mode) - 5)
  .style("fill", "steelblue")
  .style("opacity", 0.5);
  
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
  .on("drag", modeDrag);

modeRect.call(drag);


function modeDrag(modeX){
  var xPos = d3.mouse(this)[0],
      tmp = brushX.invert(xPos);
  if (tmp > min && tmp < max){
    mode = tmp;
    modeRect
    .attr('x', xPos);
    redraw();
  }
}

function brushmove() {
  console.log(d3.event)
  var extent = brush.extent();
  min = extent[0];
  max = extent[1];
  if (min >= mode){
    mode = min;
    modeRect.attr('x', brushX(mode) - 5);
  } else if (max <= mode){
    mode = max;
    modeRect.attr('x', brushX(mode) - 5);
  }
  
  redraw();
}

  </script>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    var pert = {
      min: 2,
      mode: 4,
      max: 9
    };

    pert.mu = (pert.min + 4 * pert.mode + pert.max) / 6;
    pert.a1 = 6 * (pert.mu - pert.min) / (pert.max - pert.min);
    pert.a2 = 6 * (pert.max - pert.mu) / (pert.max - pert.min);
    pert.beta = betafn(pert.a1, pert.a2);

    var data = [];

    for (var k = pert.min; k < pert.max; k += 0.1) {
      data.push({
        x: k,
        y: (1 / pert.beta) * (Math.pow(k - pert.min, pert.a1 - 1) *
            Math.pow(pert.max - k, pert.a2 - 1)) /
          Math.pow(pert.max - pert.min, pert.a1 + pert.a2 - 1)
      });
    }

    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 35,
        left: 50
      },
      width = 250 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([pert.min, pert.max])
      .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, 1])
      .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis1 = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom")
      .ticks(5)
      .innerTickSize(-6)
      .outerTickSize(0)
      .tickPadding(7);

    var yAxis1 = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left")
      .ticks(5)
      .innerTickSize(-6)
      .outerTickSize(0)
      .tickPadding(7);

    var xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("top")
      .ticks(5)
      .innerTickSize(-6)
      .tickPadding(-20)
      .outerTickSize(0)
      .tickFormat("");

    var yAxis2 = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left")
      .ticks(5)
      .innerTickSize(6)
      .tickPadding(-20)
      .outerTickSize(0)
      .tickFormat("");

    var xGrid = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom")
      .tickSize(-height, -height, 0)
      .tickFormat("");

    var yGrid = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left")
      .ticks(5)
      .tickSize(-width, -width, 0)
      .tickFormat("");

    var line = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.x);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.y);
      })
      .interpolate("linear");

    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
      .x(x)
      .y(y)
      .scaleExtent([1, 1])
      .on("zoom", redraw);

    var svg = d3.select("#plot").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
      .call(zoom);

    // Add x grid
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x grid")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xGrid);

    // Add y grid
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y grid")
      .call(yGrid);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x1 axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis1);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y1 axis")
      .call(yAxis1);

    /* append additional X axis */
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x2 axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + [0, 0] + ")")
      .call(xAxis2);

    /* append additional y axis */
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y2 axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + [width, 0] + ")")
      .call(yAxis2);

    // Add x axis label  
    svg.append("text")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + "," + (height + margin.bottom) + ")")
      .style("font-size", "15")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("x axis");

    // Add y axis label
    svg.append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
      .attr("x", 0 - (height / 2))
      .attr("dy", "1em")
      .style("font-size", "15")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("y axis");

    svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", "clip")
      .append("rect")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

    svg.append("rect")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

    svg.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")

    function redraw() {
      pert.min = min - 0.001;
      pert.mode = mode;
      pert.max = max + 0.001;
      pert.mu = (pert.min + 4 * pert.mode + pert.max) / 6;
      pert.a1 = 6 * (pert.mu - pert.min) / (pert.max - pert.min);
      pert.a2 = 6 * (pert.max - pert.mu) / (pert.max - pert.min);
      pert.beta = betafn(pert.a1, pert.a2);

      x.domain([pert.min, pert.max]);

      svg.select(".x1.axis").call(xAxis1);
      svg.select(".y1.axis").call(yAxis1);
      svg.select(".x2.axis").call(xAxis2);
      svg.select(".y2.axis").call(yAxis2);
      svg.select(".x.grid").call(xGrid);
      svg.select(".y.grid").call(yGrid);

      var data = [];

      for (var k = pert.min; k < pert.max; k += 0.1) {
        data.push({
          x: k,
          y: (1 / pert.beta) * (Math.pow(k - pert.min, pert.a1 - 1) *
              Math.pow(pert.max - k, pert.a2 - 1)) /
            Math.pow(pert.max - pert.min, pert.a1 + pert.a2 - 1)
        });
      }

      d3.select(".line").attr("d", line(data));
    }

    redraw();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and your example. The code what you created was indeed what I am looking for. However, I am not that experienced with d3 and would like a consistent layout. For that reason, I am going to try to edit the jquery slider such that it enables one to have a range with a three parameters, minimum, modal and maximum.